# Adding <nav> or any content makes my background image and the contents of my div dissapear

Tags: css, html, background-image, nav

I have a weird issue with some of my divs. Right now my divs are set up to take up the whole screen then have a background color then a background image over it. However, while everything displays properly, if I try to add any content specifically  everything disappears except for my background color. I've never had this problem before and I believe it has something to do with how my images and my div are set up. But I can't find a solution so I was wondering if any of you guys could help! I've included the html and css down below!

Here is the jsfiddle that might help: http://jsfiddle.net/e7C87/1/ the red section is the section where I'm trying to place a nav bar and where the background image dissapears

Html (the area with the  is the div that's giving me issues all the other divs displays correctly):

```
<div id="induoIntro" class="divide">
                <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#ff837b">
                    <p id="introGraphic"></p>

                    <nav>
                        <a href="#designers">Designers</a>
                        <a href="#developers">Developers</a>
                        <a href="#directors">Directors</a>              
                    </nav>

                </div>

                <div class="textBody">
                     <p>A rag-tag group of desginers, directors and developers hoping to collaborate with you in an effort to satisfy your endeavours, beautify the web, and enginneer a functional interaction; we'll even guaraantee affordability.</p>   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="designers" class="divide">                 
                <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#FFB37B">
                    <p id="designGraphic"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="textBody">
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus </p>   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="developers" class="divide">
                <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#CEE28F">
                    <p id="devGraphic"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="textBody">
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus </p>   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="directors" class="divide">
                <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#C195DA">
                    <p id="directGraphic">
                </div>

                <div class="textBody">
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus </p>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.divide {
    height:200%;
}

.graphic {
    display:table; 
    height:50%;
    width:100%;

}

.graphic p {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; 
}

#introGraphic {
    background-image: url(../images/WAInduo-02.svg);
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#designGraphic {
    background-image: url(../images/WAdesign-03.svg);
    background-size: 100% 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#devGraphic {
    background-image: url(../images/WAdevelop-04.svg);
    background-size: 100% 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
}

#directGraphic {
    background-image:url(../images/WAdirect-05.svg);
    background-size: 100% 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.textBody {    
    display:table; 
    height:50%;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
}

.textBody p {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have a lot of irrelevant code there. Here is a JSFiddle and the code that is relevant to your problem (it can be difficult to determine, but if possible, it *really* helps to provide only the requisite code that we need to solve your problem): **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hcbw/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="induoIntro" class="divide">
    <div class="graphic">
        <p>Graphic Test</p>
        <nav>Test</nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.divide {
    height: 200%;
}

.graphic {
    display: table; 
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff837b;
}

.graphic p {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

As you can see from the JSFiddle, the `<p>` contents of "Graphic Test" are appearing properly, but the `<nav>` content is not. Well, if you look at the CSS, you see that *any* `<p>` *element that is a child of an element with the* `.graphic` *class* has special instructions, namely `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align: middle;`, and `text-align: center;`.

The `<nav>` class, however, has no such special instructions. If you *remove* those instructions from your `.graphic p` selector, you'll see that "Graphic Test" disappears as well. Where is it going? You can find it using your browser's built-in code inspector, but I'll just tell you: it's moving up to the top of the document.

But wait, isn't that where your header is? Exactly. You have an absolutely positioned `header`, which means it is removed from the normal document flow and placed **on top of** the document. So, in effect **your** `<nav>` **element is being hidden by your** `header`. To illustrate this, we'll give some opacity to your header and see the element sitting behind it:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hcbw/2/)**

Now, if we go back to your original provided JSFiddle and do the same thing to the header there, this is what you'll see: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7C87/4/)**

So to solve this, you should take the CSS properties you have for `.graphic p` and copy them to a new selector, `.graphic nav`, or something similar. Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! After adding the css rules to my <nav> it displays perfectly but then my background image disappears. Is there a fix to this? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried adding text to the background image and it actually shifts the image to the left side of the screen so I can't see it. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks!